# Using jquery between two pages of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in theory i have two html pages, and one js file.

I want to save a variable that i get from the first html page (in the form of a data attribute) and then use it in the other html page.

Think of it like this — there is a link and when I click on it, it takes me to the other page but also saves a data-attribute and then uses it in that next page.

Sorry if everyone hates me because I didn't post code,  but I figured this was a straight forward enough question.

Comment: What you are looking for is **Server Side Code** --  Not jQuery/JS  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: How are you getting the variable from the first page? How are you using the variable in the second page? It would certainly help clarify if we could see what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @showdev I am getting it from a data-attribute that is located on the "link" i click on.

so imagine if it was an image gallery — i click on a thumbnail that brings me to another page and that click also captures the thumbnails data attribute. then i want to use that attribute on the next page.

Comment: @Krang look at my answer, I am sure that is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to save your variables inside the local storage...
But there are multiple ways, in my opinion it is the easiest.

**Save** something in the local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('test', variableName);
```

**Get** something out of the local storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('variableName')
```

**Delete** the local storage:

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

**Remove single item** out of the local storage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('variableName');
```

variableName in this case is the identifier of your local storage variable. You can put there whatever you want but keep in mind that there hast to be only one identifier with the same name in the local storage otherwise ther will be a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Session Storage or Local Storage

1st page:

```
$('body').on('click', '#changeRoute', function() {
   localStorage.setItem('previousId', $(this).attr('id');
});
```

2nd page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(localStorage.getItem('previousId'));
});
```

**OR** you can use url params.

1st page

```
<a href="/nextPage?key=FromFirstPage">Change Route</a>
```

2nd page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log(document.location.search.split('=')[1])
});
```